# Get User ID from within a plugin

Tags: plugins, users

I want to get the current user id from inside my plugin and use it as a variable.

My code is

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $current_user->ID;

$loc_statuss = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT status FROM profile_location INNER JOIN relation_user ON profile_location.loc_id=relation_user.loc_id WHERE relation_user.user_id=$user_id" );
$loc_status = $loc_statuss->status;
```

I have found a couple of questions the same but these answers don't seem to work for me.

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to get this value when, when the urser logs in  ?

Comment: @CesarHenriqueDamascena see my comment on the first answer should explain more how I am using it

Answer (score 1):

If you want current user id only then use get_current_user_id.
because it reduce execution time. get_current_user_id get only current user id where wp_get_current_user get all user data.
Else every things is perfect.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

$loc_statuss = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT status FROM profile_location INNER JOIN relation_user ON profile_location.loc_id=relation_user.loc_id WHERE relation_user.user_id=".$user_id );
$loc_status = $loc_statuss->status;
```

Comment: This returns a 0 rather than the user id. From what I have read its because I haven't loaded pluggable. Are you able to tell me how to do this or if there is another reason get_current_user_id returns zero? Thanks

Comment: 0 is returned if no user is logged in. Which hook are you executing this code in? If any.

Comment: If no user signed in then it returns 0. If still their is problem then use wp_get_current_user if it get id for you. Will you please tell me in which action you are writing this code or it is your custom plugin action. thanks

Comment: @RahulParikh `get_current_user_id()` uses `wp_get_current_user()` itself, so it's not going to be any faster or behave any differently.

Comment: yes @JacobPeattie

Comment: I am taking the functionality out of my theme and putting it in to a plugin for best practice reasons. I have a bunch of global variable I use throughout my code. One being $user_id and one $loc_status. All my variables worked when they were in the function file so its def something to do with moving them over to the plugin. I am not using a hook which is where I guess I am going wrong.

Comment: You can't write any code without hook. if your code is not belongs to any particular hook then write it in **init** hook.

Comment: @Dudley That's your problem, the current user hasn't been set up yet when plugins are loaded, you need to hook your functions into a later hook, like init, to be able to use information about the current user.

Comment: I've gone and done some more reading based on your comments and have added this: add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'yardstick' );
function yardstick_load_textdomain() {
  load_plugin_textdomain( 'yardstick', false, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' ); 
}

add_action( 'init', 'get_user_id' );
function get_user_id() {
 echo get_current_user_id();
}

$user_id = get_user_id();

Comment: But it still gives me nothing

Comment: If nobody is logged in then it return 0. If you are logged in as admin in wp-admin and trying to see what echo it then see it in inspect or in view page source. Thanks

Comment: Who new getting a user id in a plugin was so difficult - thanks for all your help but I can't get it to work so will go back to putting it in the function file

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
// Set up the global variables
$user_id;
$loc_status;

// When the user login, setup all variables that you need

function get_user_informations( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    if ( $user ) {
      $user_id = $user->id;

      $loc_statuss = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT status FROM profile_location INNER JOIN relation_user ON profile_location.loc_id=relation_user.loc_id WHERE relation_user.user_id=".$user_id );
      $loc_status = $loc_statuss->status;

    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'get_user_informations', 10, 3 );
```

More about `login_redirect` in the [Docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect).